# Rails: custom wrapper for submit button in simple_form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, wrapper, simple-form

I am using simple_form gem with bootstrap 3.
I want to have a wrapper for submit button

Now it shows HTML as

```
<form id="new_order" ...>
    ...

   <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Save" name="commit">
</form>
```

I want to write a wrapper so the HTML would be:

```
<form id="new_order" ...>
  ...

  <div class="form-group">
     <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
        <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Save" name="commit">
     </div>
 </div>
```

I got this so far:

app/initializers/simple_form_bootstrap.rb:

```
options[:wrapper] = :horizontal_form
options[:wrapper_mappings] = {
  check_boxes: :horizontal_radio_and_checkboxes,
  radio_buttons: :horizontal_radio_and_checkboxes,
  file: :horizontal_file_input,
  boolean: :horizontal_boolean,

 # what to write here??
 # submit: :horizontal_submit_button

}
```

and this is my wrapper:

```
  config.wrappers :horizontal_submit_button, tag: 'div', class: 'form-group', error_class: 'has-error' do |b|
     b.use :html5
     b.use :placeholder

     b.wrapper tag: 'div', class: 'col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10' do |ba|
       ba.use :input
       # some coe goes here, maybe
     end
  end
```

Which input type to use in wrapper_mappings for submit button? How to write that wrapper?

Comment: One year, 15 upvotes and still no good answer. That's sad, `simple_form`. :(

Answer (score 1):

I was looking to do the same thing today. I couldn't find a way to do it through the wrapper API, oddly, but by default Simple Form likes to wrap its inputs in a `div.form-inputs` and its submit button in a `div.form-actions`. So I styled the `div.form-actions` to `@extend .col-md-offset-4` to get the result I wanted.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Apparently it is not possible to have a wrapper for buttons using simple_form. I wanted to do the same thing and the solution I found was to replace

```
config.button_class = 'btn'
```

with

```
config.button_class = 'myclass1 myclass2'
```

in the `config/initializers/simple_form.rb` file. The problem is that it will be the default for all form buttons.

Answer (score 1):

Simple form `button` is basic wrapper around rails `submit` helper.  All it does is it adds `button_class` defined in simple form initializer and send it to `submit`, here is what it look like right now:

https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form/blob/master/lib/simple_form/form_builder.rb#L211

```
def button(type, *args, &block)
  options = args.extract_options!.dup
  options[:class] = [SimpleForm.button_class, options[:class]].compact
  args << options
  if respond_to?(:"#{type}_button")
    send(:"#{type}_button", *args, &block)
  else
    send(type, *args, &block)
  end
end
```

There is no logic for using wrapper api here. But that `if` statement lets you define your own button method. If you use `f.button :submit` in your forms than put this in an initializer (or decorator so you don't have to restart the server while customizing):

```
module SimpleForm
  class FormBuilder
    def submit_button(*args, &block)
      ActionController::Base.helpers.content_tag(:div, class: 'form-actions') do
        submit(*args, &block)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

You don't have to use `content_tag` helpers, any `html_safe` string will work.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by **@Alex** you can add a custom input if you want the wrapper in all the forms.

For a custom solution where you need to add the classes only in a few forms

You can use `content_tag` to wrap the submit button

```
<%= f.input :first_name %>
<%= f.input :last_name %>
...
<%= content_tag(:div, class: 'form-group') do %>
  <%= content_tag(:div, class: 'col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10') do %>
    <%= f.button :submit, value: 'Save', class: "btn-primary" %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

This will generate the following for the submit (not adding generated HTML for inputs here on purpose)

```
<div class="form-group">
  <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
    <input type="submit" name="commit" value="Save" class="btn btn-primary" data-disable-with="Update User">
  </div>
</div>
```